# scrcpy not working while VISUAL STUDIO CODE is working

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, adb, emulation

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and I have installed scrcpy to mirror my phone screen while creating flutter applications, but when I just open Vs code, scrcpy closes with this error ::
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...

Comment: You need a newer version of adb client.

Comment: I too am facing the same problem. I updated android platform tools to latest version, thus using newer adb version but still no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/FAQ.md#conflicts-between-adb-versions (and using a non-snap version of scrcpy may help)

Answer (score 2):

this error is Conflicts between adb versions
https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/FAQ.md#conflicts-between-adb-versions

Solution is set **ADB** env is path to Android Sdk platform-tools adb

> /home//Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb

in Linux, you can

```
export ADB=/path/to/your/adb
```

in Win,

```
set ADB=/path/to/your/adb
```

Answer (score 1):

Same things was happened for me in Android Studio during Flutter App development.
So my solution for  Android Studio running on Ubuntu 20.04 is given below:

**Solution:**

Please do the following steps:

1. If you have "Android SDK Platform tools" installed then please uninstall it from "Android Studio --> Tools --> SDK Manager --> SDK Tools(Tab)"
2. Now, please mark "Android SDK Platform tools" from the list that is found under "SDK Tools(Tab)". The path of "SDK Tools(Tab)" is "Android Studio --> Tools --> SDK Manager --> SDK Tools(Tab)". After that, press "OK" button to install.
3. Then, from terminal, please type following command to check the presence of "adb" file under "Android --> Sdk --> platform-tools"

"cd /home//Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ && ls"

4. After that, please remove current adb file from "/usr/bin" and then copy adb file to "/usr/bin" from "/home//Android/Sdk/platform-tools/" using following commands:

"sudo rm /usr/bin/adb && sudo cp /home//Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/"

5. Finally, please restart the adb server using following commands:

"kill adb-server && start adb-server"

6. Now, please check either everything is ok or not using following commands:

"adb version && adb devices"

Comment: this doesnot work for me

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Linux, you can take the adb path:

**1. First get your adb path.**

*example: /home/Your-User/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb*

**2. Second open your terminal or terminal emulator and paste the line in the example to edit the .bashrc file.**

**example:**

`code ~/.bashrc`

**at the end of the line add this:**

`export ADB=/home/Your-User/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`

**save the changes and return to the terminal then refresh the shell with this:** `source ~/.bashrc` or *close the terminal and reopen it.*

<s>**3. You must always run this command when restarting your terminal.**</s>

**no need for step 3**. *NB: adb must follow after* **`platform-tools/`**

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have recently found solution for this issue. Since it is impossible 2 adb work in the same time, you should use one of them. To implement this:

1. open vscode
2. in vscode terminal $export ADB=/home/your_username/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb scrcpy   run this command
3. Then run $scrcpy command as well.
   I hope it works. However you should do above steps every time you open vscode!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu try this, open up your terminal: `ctrl + alt + t`

First check if you have adb in your platform-tools directory.

Enter this commands to check first:

`cd /home/change-this-to-your-username/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/`

`ls`

You should see **adb** listed in your terminal.

If yes, do not close your terminal yet, and open up another terminal: `ctrl + alt + t`

Enter command:

1. `cd /usr/bin` - changes directory to usr/bin
2. `sudo rm adb` - this will remove adb

Now go back to your previous terminal.

Enter command:

`sudo cp adb /usr/bin` - this will copy your existing adb from platform-tools directory to usr/bin where you deleted another version of adb.

now if you run: `scrcpy`

Terminal will show a log that you don't have adb installed.

Go back to your terminal and run: `vim .bashrc`

> If you don't have vim installed on your machine, enter: `sudo apt install vim`

Press 'i' key on your keyboard to insert path: `export ADB='/usr/bin/adb'`

`ctrl + shift + v` to paste it in terminal

Press 'esc' key on your keyboard and type a colon `:` or `shift + ;` type x and hit 'enter' key to save.

run: `scrcpy`